# Relative multiplicative vs. absolute additive error propagation

Tags: error-analysis

I am using the physics Cambridge book (Tsokos, K. (2014). *Physics for the IB Diploma*. 6th ed. Cambridge University Press.) for the International Baccalaureate and I noticed the following:

When it comes to error propagation we have the following two rules:

1. If $Q=a+b$ and $\Delta a$ is the uncertainty of $a$ and $\Delta b$ is the uncertainty of $b$ then the uncertainty of Q is the sum of the uncertainties on a and b.
2. I read on a separate document that has a rule that says you don’t count the constants while finding uncertainty.

The book gives some problems like the one where one has to find the uncertainty of the energy in the equation: 
$$ E= (1/2) mv^2,$$
the propagation of error equation was 
$$\Delta E/E = \Delta m/m + 2 (\Delta v/v).$$
The good thing here is that the rule above applies (the author ignored the constant $1/2$ as if it weren’t there).

What concerns me is in another exercise the author says find the uncertainty on $Q$ where $Q=2a +2b$. I initially ignored the constants 2 above and said that $\Delta Q = \Delta a + \Delta b$. It turns out the answer was  $\Delta Q = 2\Delta a + 2\Delta b$. How is this possible? Why was the constant not ignored in this error propagation?

Comment: Hint: The formulas are for $\Delta Q$ and $\Delta E/E$, that is, one is for the relative uncertainty and the other for the absolute uncertainty.

Comment: Change the 2 to 2,000,000. Is it reasonable to expect $2,000,000 Q$ to have the same uncertainty as $Q$?

Answer (score 2):

The constants are ignored when finding the *fractional* uncertainty, but not the absolute uncertainty.

Say you have some $Q = \alpha a$. Then the absolute uncertainty in $Q$ is $\Delta Q=\alpha \Delta a$. But when finding the fractional uncertainty, $\frac{\Delta Q}{Q}=\frac{\alpha \Delta a}{\alpha a}=\frac{\Delta a}{a}$. Both $Q$ and $\Delta Q$ are proportional to $\alpha$, so their ratio is independent of it.